# modify URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to change url for example http://www.mysite.com/cgshop/admin/index.php?route=common/home will become http://www.mysite.com/cgshop/cp/index.php?route=common/home.
Please help me to figure out this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should take a look at this site http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Answer (score 1):

This should get you what you want.

It tests to see if the URI begins with `/cgshop/admin/` and then captures the rest so it can redirect with a 301 to the new url.  The `QSA` means it will also carry over the query string (everything after the `?`).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cgshop/admin/.*$
RewriteRule ^cgshop/admin/(.*)$ /cgshop/cp/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cgshop/cp/.*$ cgshop/admin/$1
```

Try this.......